WSO2 APIM 4.2.0 gives 401 Invalid Credentials error while authenticating API using OAuth2
WSO2 APIM giving authentication failure while I am trying to authenticate API using OAuth2 but working fine with apikey. No change implemented at configs level and it was working earlier fine but now giving below error
{
  "code": "900901",
  "message": "Invalid Credentials",
  "description": "Access failure for API: /letshego-api-gw/test/v1, version: v1 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
}

I have checked the DB table IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN and the token_state is ACTIVE.
Below errors are coming in the logs while hitting the API
[2024-04-30 14:50:04,455]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials for requestURI=/letshego-api-gw/test/v1/test/mock

I am using Resident KeyManager for authentication and Postgres DB for configs.
What could be the reason for this issue?

Are you invoking the API using the devportal console? If you are using JWTs and you generated a new tokens multiple times from the same application, only the latest token will be valid. You need to make sure you are using the latest token generated.

I am trying to use devportal and from the curl as well Also I am using the newly created token but still it gives 401 error.

The issue has been resolved as the column configuration in the table am_key_manager under the apim_db has been somehow corrupted which gives an authentication error. After updating the configuration column by updating the value from the fresh APIM. It gets resolved.
